# Which states are you able to press Z to catch an item?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

I know it is possible to catch an item by pressing Z while standing still and while in the air. I am guessing it is probably also possible while running. I'm wondering if it is also possible while performing moves, or perhaps in other states like hanging on the ledge. Are there any obscure states your character can be in where you can still catch items by pressing Z?

Here is a list of all the possible states a character can be in: http://smashboards.com/threads/list-of-all-possible-character-states-ie-downdamage-downwait.400270/

Comment: There are hundreds of character states there. While your question is valid, I feel any answers will be far too broad for our format.

Comment: ＠Kaizerwolf That being said, it is actually a list of global animations. They have a lot of overlap with various character states, but the states can be grouped into several major categories. I'm not an expert on Melee so much as I am one of Brawl, but AFAIK it's not possible to Z-catch items while doing attacks, nor while dashing. States related to things like like hitting the ground, performing an air dodge, hanging on the ledge, or such, can be excluded as well. States where there might be ambiguity due to various factors include dropping from a platform, jumping, or being in landing lag.

Comment: Of course, there is no real ambiguity to any of these situations - they are governed by clear, distinct rules - but it may be very difficult for human players to discern some of the fine details which may result to one state acting in a certain way in one situation and in a different way in another. In practice, such ambiguities are avoided by doing actions that will allow the player to Z-catch items in a consistent manner, when the the possible need for a Z-catch is anticipated. Also noteworthy is that although catching items during a dash may not be possible, the player can jump at any time.